# How to close the popup modal when we click on save or cancel button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, popover

I have an angular application, In that I have created the popover using angular.

**.component.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 ">
          <div class="cc button-popover" >
          <popover-content #addObjectivePopovers
          [animation]="true"
          [closeOnClickOutside]="false"
          [closeOnMouseOutside]="false" class="vb" *ngIf="!showPopover" >

    <form >
          <div class="form-group popover-form" >
              <label>Enter Custom Trigger Habit: When I</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name"></textarea>
              
          </div><br>
            <div class="form-group popover-form">
              <label>Enter Custom Trigger Habit: I will</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" #customHabit id="power" maxlength="1500" [(ngModel)]="name2" name="name2"></textarea>
              <p class="textarea-count">({{1500 - customHabit.value.length }} of 1500 Characters remaining)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="popover-btn">
              <button  class="btn btn-default " (click)="showPopover = false">CANCEL</button>
              <button type="button" (click)="save()" >SAVE</button>
            </div>
      </form>
</popover-content>
</div>

<button [popoverOnHover]="false" type="button" popoverPlacement="bottom"   [popover]="addObjectivePopovers" >ADD CUSTOM HABIT</button>
        </div>
```

So when I add some content in textarea and click on the save button I has to close the popup ,and also when we click on the cancel also It should close the popup.

Can anyone help on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `show` boolean flag is separate from the visible state of the popover then add a new boolean flag to your component ts which will be used to manage the visible state of the popover and toggle it with your cancel/save controls:

component ts:

```
showPopover = false

save() {
  this.show = true;
  this.showPopover = false;
}
```

component html:

```
<div class="form-group popover-form" *ngIf="showPopover">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="power" maxlength="1500" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
    <button  class="btn btn-default cancel-btn" (click)="showPopover = false">CANCEL</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="save()">SAVE</button>
</div>

<p *ngIf="show">{{name}}</p>
```

Comment: @I have edited my all exact htmlcode which I am using, but when I click on the save button or cancel the popup is not closing.Could you please help me on the same

Comment: Is your popover a custom component or bootstrap/other?

Comment: custom one I have created

Comment: where were you adding the `save()` and the `showPopover` property?